# Does your PSN account country/region have to match your geographical position, your payment method's, both, or neither, or..?

Tags: psn, ps-now

- I live in the Netherlands for the foreseeable future
- I want to use PS Now, which is available atm in UK, Belgium, and Netherlands (only?)
- My payment method, however, is Italian
- I want to use the service in English, if at all possible

However, Sony asks me to pick one "country/region."

[image]

What do I have to choose?

Answer (score 1):

PSN won't accept debit/credit cards unless they're from the same region the account is [registered](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Network-Support/Credit-card-payment-in-different-region/td-p/40357523) to. If you want to use your Credit card, you should register under Italy, but you will be unable to use PSNow, as it hasn't released in Italy yet. If you want to access PSNow, register under Netherlands and buy prepaid cards to make purchases on PSN. The service language is under Language, not region. So picking Netherlands nor Italy has no effect on language

Comment: I really doubt I'll be able to sign up for a subscription service without a credit card number. OH WELL

Comment: Not necessarily. I cannot confirm this, but as it's linked to PSN, you might be able to credit your PSN account with the money, and pay Per month, like can be done with PS+

Comment: So, as an example; you put on the £15ish, pay £15, you get a month. It cancels automatically after unless you can continue to fund the subscription.

Comment: You can subscribe without a credit card.  As @BritishFerret says, you can use prepaid cards.  All PSN subscripts can be extended manually at any time with funds from the wallet, which can be filled from a PSN card.

Comment: @badp Jochem and I use Paypal for our PSN purposes. As an alternative, you could set up a Paypal account connected to your Dutch account for Dutch usage. My PSN account is NA, his is EU. We use his Paypal for his account and transfer money from his to my Paypal account when I need to pay for stuff on PSN. In addition, you could just buy PSN cards at GameMania or other Dutch stores here that sell PSN wallet cards (those work on Jochem's EU account but not my NA account; all codes are region-locked).

Comment: @FAE Hmm, I have a different experience with Paypal. I live in Germany and have a UK account and when I tried adding money to my PSN with my German Paypal the payment was instantly reversed. I don't have a credit card associated with it, so maybe that makes a difference, but Paypal never worked for me to get around the region difference.

Comment: @Kodama Apologies, I think my meaning wasn't clear. We transfer money from his EU PayPal account to my US PayPal account in order to use my US PayPal on my NA PSN. I indeed have the same experience as you if I try to use his.

Comment: This seems rather complex. Surely it's easiest to buy an Eu PSN cash card online from Italy and then redeem it in NL. That should work?

Comment: Or a physical card from a store in NL

Comment: I wrote before that you can't use iDEAL, so I bought a card... and while activating the card, I see iDEAL as a payment option :/ you just have to click on ["Bedrag toevoegen aan de portemonnee"](https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/liquid/cam/account/mywallet/select-payment-instrument.action)

Comment: also [it appears you HAVE to have a credit card for PS Now](http://i.imgur.com/s3VvbI2.png)

Comment: Apparently the card is required, but it will draw from psn funds first if it can

Comment: Apparently [you can avoid having a card if you skip the trial](https://t.co/H74MY6fEkL) but [you can't skip the trial](https://twitter.com/AskPS_UK/status/770708071278645248)?

Comment: Might sound a little off-pace, but would a debit card work? Couldn't you register for one in a NL bank if you're staying there a while?

Comment: @BritishFerret Dutch debit card systems use iDeal, which is what he mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no geographical checking.  You can register an account from any physical location provided you can give the appropriate postal code/city/state province for the country.  You *do* have to have a method of payment for country your account is from to make purchases.

Some people get around this by purchasing PSN cards.  For example, if you are a US resident but want to play games purchased from the Japanese store, you can create a Japanese account and purchase Japanese PSN cards from someplace like [playasia.com](http://www.play-asia.com/search/psn+card).  Note that PSN cards can only be used with accounts from the country they were purchased for.

Games on PS4 are not region-locked, so you can purchase/play games for any country while physically in any country.  Video is a different matter, and video is generally licensed based on *physical* location.  You cannot watch Videos purchased from the US store outside the physical US for example, and cannot use PlayStation Vue outside the US.